# How to convert js code to angular 2

Tags: angular

How i can convert this js function on angular 2?

This is a function of pie chart:

```
$(function() {

var data = [{
    label: "Series 0",
    data: 1
}, {
    label: "Series 1",
    data: 3
}, {
    label: "Series 2",
    data: 9
}, {
    label: "Series 3",
    data: 20
}];

var plotObj = $.plot($("#flot-pie-chart"), data, {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        content: "%p.0%, %s", // show percentages, rounding to 2 decimal places
        shifts: {
            x: 20,
            y: 0
        },
        defaultTheme: false
    }
});
```

And how to show in html? With class or something else? Maybe ngShow? 
This code to solve some pie chart.

Comment: are you using angular-cli for your project ?

Comment: @pd farhad i dont know what it this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a angular2 directive like this:

```
declare var $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: 'pie-flot',
  host: {
    '[style.display]': '"block"',
    '[style.width]': '"300px"',
    '[style.height]': '"300px"'
  }
})
export class PieFlotDirective {
  @Input() data: any;
  plotObj: any;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.plotObj = $.plot($(this.elRef.nativeElement), this.data, {
      series: {
        pie: {
          show: true
        } 
      },
      grid: {
        hoverable: true
      },
      tooltip: true,  
      tooltipOpts: {
        content: "%p.0%, %s",
        shifts: {
          x: 20,
          y: 0
        },
        defaultTheme: false
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.plotObj.destroy();
  }
}
```

And then use it:

```
<pie-flot [data]="data"></pie-flot>
```

The corresponding plunkr is located [**here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/eWx7AmBo5dQAE3fhbpNV?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for quickly answer! But now i have this error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: and how i can use *ngFor with this chart? i

Comment: `declare var $: any;`

Comment: thanks a lot, and last question, how i cat change legend position? for example in righr turn on chart?

Comment: See this customization https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-legend. I've updated https://plnkr.co/edit/eWx7AmBo5dQAE3fhbpNV?p=preview

Comment: when i use *ngFor: `<pie-flot *ngFor="let list of lists" [data]="list.system.memory.data"></pie-flot>` Ive got this error: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Can you reproduce it in plunker? Possible you have wrong data

Comment: I can't find a place where you're using `[data]="list.system.memory.data"`. Can you provide a simple working plunker?

Comment: monitorng.form.component.html -> and list down